# How to use master method or recursion problem in case of f(n)=n factorial

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, master-theorem

How to solve T(n) =2T(n/2)+n! using master method or recursion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The case is straightforward in master theorem. As `log_2(2) = 1` and `n \in O(n!)`, the result will be `T(n) \in Theta(n!)`. Hence, `T(n) \in O(n!)`.